# Identify boardgame from Big movie

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone know what the game pictured in the background of this scene is? It's got the logo from the fictitious toy company from the movie in it, so it's plausible the game is fictitious too. If it is, it really reminds me of a game from my childhood but I can't figure out what!

I've sharpened and brightened the image as best I can.

[image: Unknown boardgame]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is [Cathedral](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/29653/mattel-english-edition-1986), specifically the Mattel edition.

You can see the same colour figurines, the circular towers and the picture is the same as the box but mirrored.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it could be [Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_(board_game)).

Comment: Could you edit in some information about why you think this is the answer?  One-liner answers and link-only answers tend not to be well received on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm really not sure what more to write than they "look like" each other. It's the only thing I can go by.

Comment: Malkev's post is an excellent example.  It includes a picture so that you don't have to follow a link to see what the game looks like, and describes some of the similarities.